# Show that $X \in L^p$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent variables and $p \geq 1$. Show that $X + Y \in L^p$ $\implies$ $X, Y \in L^p$. I tried using the inequalities
$$|X + Y|^p \leq 2^{p}(|X|^p + |Y|^p),$$
and
$$|X|^p \leq 2^{p}(|X + Y|^p + |Y|^p),$$
but I didn't get anything useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is proved using Fubini's Theorem. We have $\int(E|x+Y|^{p})dF_X(x) <\infty$ and this implies that $E|x+Y|^{p} <\infty$  for at least one $x$. ( In fact for almost all $x$ w.r.t. $F_X$!). Now you can  see that $E|Y|^{p} <\infty$? from the inequality $|Y|^{p} \leq 2^{p} (|x+Y|^{p}+|x|^{p})$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it at all, I know Fubini's theorem, but I don't understand why $\int(E|x + Y|^p)dF_X(x)$, this is my first course of measure theory. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The joint distrbution of $(X,Y)$ is a product measure and $Ef(X,Y) =\int \int f(x,y) dF_X (x)dF_Y(y)=\int \int f(x,y) dF_Y(y)dF_X (x)$ for any bounded or non-negative measurable function $f$. @math_27181